# How to include .a file in Atmel Studio on Windows?

Tags: static-libraries, avr, atmega, atmel, .a

I'm trying to interface [BME680](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/environmental-sensors/gas-sensors/bme680/) gas sensor module with AVR controller (Atmega644p to be specific) using Atmel Studio in Windows platform.
The BME680 does come with example functions multiple .h,.c files for configuration and one .a (static library). .h and .c files are calling some functions from static library as well, so we need to include all available .h, .c and .a files.

.a file was new to me and after basic web search I concluded that .a files are for Unix as .lib files are in Windows.

So can you find me a way to either:

convert my in hand .a file to .lib file?
or
to add .a file in Atmel studio in Windows platform?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I did try to include .a file using following steps:

1. In Project=>Properties
2. click on the Toolchain tab Under XC8 Linker
3. click on Libraries In the Libraries (-l) window
4. click the "+" sign and add "libalgobsec" to the list In the Library
   search path (-L) window
5. click on the "+" sign In the "Add Library search path (-L) dialog
6. click on the "..." button In the file dialog, navigate to the folder
   that contains libalgobsec.a
7. Click okay.
8. Under Project Properties => XC8 Linker => Miscellaneous => Other
   Objects, add: -u _fstat -u _read -u _write

But it gives this error: [Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMM82.png).

Comment: I did try to include .a file using following steps:

In Project=>Properties, click on the Toolchain tab
Under XC8 Linker, click on Libraries
In the Libraries (-l) window, click the "+" sign and add "libalgobsec" to the list
In the Library search path (-L) window, click on the "+" sign
In the "Add Library search path (-L) dialog, click on the "..." button
In the file dialog, navigate to the folder that contains libalgobsec.a
Click okay.
Under Project Properties => XC8 Linker => Miscellaneous => Other Objects, add:
    -u _fstat
    -u _read
    -u _write

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good description.  You'll need to post actual error complete messages.  But if they provide .c files, you probably can just compile those yourself and ignore the .a file, and that is preferable in case there are bugs in the code or you just want to understand what is going on in it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thank you for response, I couldn't find a way to attach image in comment so I have updated the original question.
Basically .h and .c files are calling some functions from static library as well, so we need to add all .h, .c and .a files.

Comment: The error message shows that the compiler found your .a file but skipped it because it's incompatible.  Where exactly did you find the file and how do you know it is compatible with AVRs?  Maybe it's a Linux library or something.

Comment: So BOSCH does provide support for different controllers, as the package downloaded from its website has support for [these] (https://i.imgur.com/BOqf3Eu.png) controller and AVR has [these](https://i.imgur.com/sdmCGxk.png) sub-folders and each sub-folder has [these](https://i.imgur.com/MapQaKQ.png) files along with some generic configuration [files](https://i.imgur.com/j0RRTDP.png) (and an Arduino example)

I've tried .a file from AVR8_megaAVR and AVR8_XMEGA folder but it gives same error.

Comment: It also comes with an integration guide, in case it helps https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=017610a3-30cd-480e-b98d-ba3b1b3c9034&fn=BST-BME680-Integration-Guide-AN008-48.pdf&ct=1616095826219&tl=share-document&rf=link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 months of experiments, coordination with BOSCH and everything, here is the conclusion.

Pre-compiled library is only compatible with AVR controllers having Boot Memory of 256 Kbytes, and only following 4 controllers make it to list:

1. ATmega2561
2. ATmega2564RFR2
3. ATmega2560
4. ATmega256RFR2

So if you try to compile libalgobsec.a available in BSEC software for Atmega controllers with any other controller than mentioned above (in my case Atmega644P), it simply doesn't compile.